# Issue with Push Notifications on Xamarin Android - PendingIntent Error

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I've implemented push notifications for my Xamarin application, and everything works smoothly on iOS. However, when the Android application is put in the background or closed, notifications fail to reach the device, and an error is encountered:

**Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE; only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g., 'if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.'**

My app's version is 33, Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs version is 4.1.0, and Xamarin.Forms version is 5.0.0.2337. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public void OnPushNotificationReceived(Context context, INotificationMessage message)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, message.Title);
intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message.Body);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetContentTitle(message.Title)
    .SetContentText(message.Body)
    .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.abc_btn_check_material))
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ateshgah_loading)
    .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
    .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);

builder.SetFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

Notification notification = builder.Build();
manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can recheck your problem by following steps as follows:

1.try to update all your firebase libraries and google libraries to the latest;

2.try to add `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to your pending intents.

Here is an example :

```
        var intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));

        var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
            ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable
            : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;
        var pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, requestCode, intent, pendingIntentFlags);
```

For more information, you can check this link: [PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

Comment: I think @Mammad used Azure Library not Firebase. For token and receive Notifaction. Same problem happened on me. What is the AndroidX.Runtime?

Comment: Hi @Mammand, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT , No, I still haven't solved the problem. If you have another solution suggestion, please share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried my code ?

Comment: Yes, I tried your code but I got the same error again.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?